# How to put JSON content into <ul> tag and form in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I convert java map into JSON map (JSON is saved in file) like that:

```
{"Luigi":{"name":"Luigi","cf":"lg","pi":"123","telephone":"333","website":"site.it","sector":"Engineer","address":"Italy"},"Davide":{"name":"Davide","cf":"dvd","pi":"123456789","telephone":"755921","website":"mysite.it","sector":"Software developer","address":"Italy"}}
```

In my jsp I have a form with the same fields of the JSON map (name, cf, telephone..).

I would to put all keys of JSON map (Luigi and Davide) into an unordered list. 
Like that:

```
<ul> 
    <li>Luigi</li> 
    <li>Davide</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one of them, I would that the respective values were put into the form.

I was thinking about jQuery to do that.

**Update, form code**:

```
<form>                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Customer Name:</label>
        <input id="nameCustomer" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name customer" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Fiscal Code:</label>
        <input id="fiscalCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fiscal code">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">VAT Number:</label>
        <input id="vat" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="VAT number (if available)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Phone:</label>
        <input id="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">E-Mail:</label>
        <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Website:</label>
        <input id="website" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer's Website (if available)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Address:</label>
        <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer's Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Sector:</label>
        <input id="sector" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Sector">
    </div>
    <input id="createCustomer" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="text-align: center" value="Save Data" />
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="Clear Form">
                    </form>
```

Comment: Where is the markup for your form? And how would you match each key in the user object to the form elements?

Comment: Parse JSON and loop through it, Get `name` and append it to `<li>`!

Comment: You will have to show what you tried or people may downvote your post.

Comment: @Terry, sorry. Now I update the post with form code.

Comment: @Dhaval Marthak, ok, but I need to take the key first.

Comment: @Grimbode, I wasn't trying to do nothing yet. I was thinking the best way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy is simple:

1. Use `$.each()` to loop through your object, and insert the key into the unordered list. Insert key value in `data` attribute for future reference
2. Bind click events to the list items. Retrieve key value from `data` attribute and loop through the object associated with the key
3. Populate form inputs, identified by ID, using key-value pairs from each object associated with the user

Note that however, there are mismatches between the input IDs and certain keys in your JSON file:

- `name`in JSON but `nameCustomer` in form.
- `cf`, `pi` are present in the JSON form but are not mapped to any form input elements.

```js
var userData = {
  "Luigi": {
    "name": "Luigi",
    "cf": "lg",
    "pi": "123",
    "telephone": "333",
    "website": "site.it",
    "sector": "Engineer",
    "address": "Italy"
  },
  "Davide": {
    "name": "Davide",
    "cf": "dvd",
    "pi": "123456789",
    "telephone": "755921",
    "website": "mysite.it",
    "sector": "Software developer",
    "address": "Italy"
  }
};

// Get usernames
$.each(userData, function(key, value) {
  $('#users').append('<li data-user="' + key + '">' + key + '</li>');
});


// Bind click event to list items
$(document).on('click', '#users > li', function() {
  var user = $(this).data('user');
  $.each(userData[user], function(key, value) {
    $('form').find('#' + key).val(value);
  });
});
```

```css
#users li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="users"></ul>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Customer Name:</label>
    <input id="nameCustomer" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name customer" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Fiscal Code:</label>
    <input id="fiscalCode" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Fiscal code">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">VAT Number:</label>
    <input id="vat" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="VAT number (if available)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Phone:</label>
    <input id="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">E-Mail:</label>
    <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Website:</label>
    <input id="website" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer's Website (if available)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Address:</label>
    <input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer's Address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control">Sector:</label>
    <input id="sector" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Sector">
  </div>
  <input id="createCustomer" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="text-align: center" value="Save Data" />
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="Clear Form">
</form>
```

Comment: You are depriving him of any fun, c'mon ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios To see it in a different light, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: My answer was written before the question was edited ;)

Comment: Thank yoy @Terry! I have a question: **var user = $(this).data('user');** what is 'user'?

Comment: That would refer to the HTML5 `data-user` attribute stored for each list item.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But, why the only fields filled are phone, website, address and sector?
----
Last question :)
If I use your userData var code works. But my JSON content is stored into a string. I tried to convert it with **var userData = JSON.stringify(jsonString);** but chrome console gives me an error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '319'**

Comment: @DavideFruci Did you read the comments in my answer? The fields that are not filled do not have their ids present as keys in the object. That is why they are not filled. If you want to make sure they are filled, either (1) change the key in the JSON object so that they match the IDs or (2) change the IDs so they match the relevant keys in the JSON object.

Comment: @DavideFruci Why would you convert your JSON into string? You can't use `$.each()` on strings. It only works with arrays and objects. Just pass the `jsonString` directly to `userData`, or replace all instances of `userData` with `jsonString`.

Comment: @Terry, Thanks, for the fields not filled, now I understand and I resolved it. 
--- Sorry but I'm wrong. I have a string that content JSON string. I would convert this string into a JSON object. How can I do that?

**UPDATE** I resolve with: JSON.parse
Thank you very much Terry!! :)

Comment: @DavideFruci Glad that you've managed to resolve those issues. If this answer has helped, please accept it.

Comment: @Terry, I have another question. If I would show a single value of customer in the list instead the key, for example the fiscal code, how could I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery and [dna.js](http://dnajs.org) to make a clickable list of customers that populates the HTML form with each click.

Setup the libraries:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/dna.js/latest/dna.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/dna.js/latest/dna.min.js"></script>
```

Create two templates (one for the list of customers and one for the form):

```
<ul> 
    <li id=customer class=dna-tempalte
       data-click=populateForm>~~name~~</li> 
</ul>
<div>
<form id=customer-form class=dna-template>                        
   <div class=form-group>
      <label class=form-control>Customer Name:</label>
      <input id=nameCustomer class=form-control
         placeholder="Name customer" autofocus value=~~name~~>
   </div>
   <div class=form-group>
      <label class=form-control>Fiscal Code:</label>
      <input id=fiscalCode class=form-control
         placeholder="Fiscal code" value=~~cf~~>
   </div>
   <div class=form-group>
      <label class=form-control>VAT Number:</label>
      <input id=vat class=form-control
         placeholder="VAT number (if available)" value=~~pi~~>
   </div>
   <div class=form-group>
      <label class=form-control>Phone:</label>
      <input id=telephone class=form-control
         placeholder="Phone number" value=~~telephone~~>
   </div>
   <input id=createCustomer type=button class="btn btn-default" value="Save Data">
   <input class="btn btn-default" type=reset value="Clear Form">
</form>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript, convert the raw JSON into an array for easier handling and fill in the templates:

```
var raw = {"Luigi":{"name":"Luigi","cf":"lg","pi":"123","telephone":"333","website":"site.it","sector":"Engineer","address":"Italy"},"Davide":{"name":"Davide","cf":"dvd","pi":"123456789","telephone":"755921","website":"mysite.it","sector":"Software developer","address":"Italy"}};
function customer(name) { return raw[name]; }
var customers = Object.keys(raw).map(customer);  //convert to array

function populateForm(elem) {  //called on each click
   var model = dna.getModel(elem);
   dna.clone('customer-form', model, { empty: true });
   }
dna.clone('customer', customers);  //clickable customer list
```

Note that I'm a dna.js contributor.

Fiddle with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ggphr0ro/5/

Answer (score 3):

Iterate your JSON object, then add an `<li>` for every element:

```js
var jsonObject = '{"Luigi":{"name":"Luigi","cf":"lg","pi":"123","telephone":"333","website":"site.it","sector":"Engineer","address":"Italy"},"Davide":{"name":"Davide","cf":"dvd","pi":"123456789","telephone":"755921","website":"mysite.it","sector":"Software developer","address":"Italy"}}';

$(function() {
  $.each($.parseJSON(jsonObject), function(key,value){
    $("#myUl").append("<li>"+key+"</li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Comment: This answer the question before it was edited, obviously. The remaining part is taking the attributes from the "value" var and put them in your form's fields.